# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - using datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry didn't find any other fix, so I created a new question.
I'm trying to run a code that prints to the screen the current hour, minute and second. The piece of code I'm using to do this is:

```
def time():
    import datetime
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    print ('Right now it's %s hours, %s minutes and %s seconds.' % (nowTime.hour,nowTime.minute,nowTime.second))
    time.sleep(5)
```

I get the following error when this piece of code tries to execute:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/Teolicht/Desktop/Python/testy.py", line 219, in <module>
>     start()
>   File "/Users/Teolicht/Desktop/Python/testy.py", line 18, in start
>     questions()
>   File "/Users/Teolicht/Desktop/Python/testy.py", line 34, in questions
>     day()
>   File "/Users/Teolicht/Desktop/Python/testy.py", line 52, in day
>     time()
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
> ```

`start()`, `questions()` and `day()` are some other functions the program went through before going through `time()`. If I try executing `time()` directly, it works! So, here's the entire code from the start till the end of the `time()` function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random
import sys

def start():
    import time
    name = input('Hi. What is your name? ')
    print ('Nice to meet you, ' + str(name) + '.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('How old are you?')
    age = input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print (age + '! Cool.')
    time.sleep(2)
    questions()

def questions():
    import time
    print ('Some things you can ask me:')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('• What day is today? (qdh)')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('• What time is it? (qhs)')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('• I want to play a game! (qjj)')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('• How many days till my birthday? (qda)')
    time.sleep(1)
    questionsAnswer = input()
    if questionsAnswer == 'qdh':
        day()
    elif questionsAnswer == 'qhs':
        time()
    elif questionsAnswer == 'qjj':
        game()
    else:
        birthday()

def day():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    nowDay = datetime.now()
    print ('Today is %s/%s/%s' % (nowDay.day,nowDay.month,nowDay.year))
    time.sleep(2)
    dayAnswer = input('Want to know what time it is? "Y" for yes and "N" for no: ').lower()
    if dayAnswer == 'n':
        questions()
    else:
        time()

def time():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    print ('Right now it's %s hours, %s minutes and %s seconds.' % (nowTime.hour,nowTime.minute,nowTime.second))
    time.sleep(5)
        questions()
       ...
```

It might be something in `start()`, `questions()` or `day()` causing the error. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you mean `time.time()` in the last line of your `day` function?

Comment: You `import time` *inside a function named `time`*? It's not surprising you're confused about what's in scope.

Comment: That's right jonrsharpe

Comment: "The piece of code I'm using to do this is:" Please note that this **does not agree with** the full code shown below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worked for me, try to not create your own time() method, I renamed it to "my_time()".

The time module defines a lot of functions so, or you just "import time" or you need to specify each function you wanna import like "from time import sleep"

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time, sleep
import random
import sys

def questions():
    print ('Some things you can ask me:')
    sleep(1)
    print ('• What day is today? (qdh)')
    sleep(1)
    print ('• What time is it? (qhs)')
    sleep(1)
    print ('• I want to play a game! (qjj)')
    sleep(1)
    print ('• How many days till my birthday? (qda)')
    sleep(1)
    questionsAnswer = input()
    if questionsAnswer == 'qdh':
        day()
    elif questionsAnswer == 'qhs':
        my_time()
    elif questionsAnswer == 'qjj':
        my_game()
    else:
        my_birthday()

def day():
    sleep(1)
    nowDay = datetime.now()
    print ('Today is %s/%s/%s' % (nowDay.day,nowDay.month,nowDay.year))
    sleep(2)
    dayAnswer = input('Want to know what time it is? "Y" for yes and "N" for no: ').lower()
    if dayAnswer == 'n':
        questions()
    else:
        my_time()

def my_time():
    sleep(1)
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    print ('Right now it\'s %s hours, %s minutes and %s seconds.' % (nowTime.hour, nowTime.minute, nowTime.second))
    sleep(5)
    questions()

def my_game():
    pass

def my_birthday():
    pass

#def start():
name = input('Hi. What is your name? ')
print ('Nice to meet you, ' + str(name) + '.')
sleep(1)
print ('How old are you?')
age = input()
sleep(1)
print (age + '! Cool.')
sleep(2)
questions()
```

Comment: Thanks! Renaming `my_time()` and changing `datetime.now()` to `datetime.datetime.now` fixed the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

In your command

```
nowTime = datetime.now()
```

`datetime` is the *module* which has no method `now()`.

You probably wanted

```
nowTime = datetime.datetime.now()
```

where the first `datetime` is the `module`, and the second one is the `class` in it - with the classmethod `now()` which creates an `object` with current local date and time.

Comment: Read the exception carefully. The `datetime` module _is not_ his problem. He _is_ using `datetime.datetime` by doing `from datetime import datetime`. As Jonrsharpe already said, he's calling the `time` module inside of his function also named `time`.

Comment: @Christian - You are partially right - my answer fixes just the OP `time()` function. Importing the `time` module inside its `time()` function is definitely a bad idea - but *without* bad consequences for executing it as the `import` statement imports names into *its own* name space.

Comment: Renaming `time()` to `my_time()` and changing `datetime.now()` to `datetime.datetime()` fixed it now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

Replace your `import time` to `from time import time`.